# what is en.v9.com and how to remove it?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, malware, malware-removal

I was reinstalling Windows (namely installing Windows 8 instead of Windows 7). But then Chrome suddenly closed. When I started it again, it had that annoying [en.v9.com](http://en.v9.com/?utm_source=b&utm_medium=eBP&utm_campaign=eBP&utm_content=hp&from=eBP&uid=WDCXWD5000AAKX-001CA0_WD-WCAYUEK9947799477&ts=1379096550) home page.

I don't know how to get rid of it. I tried removing the argument in Chrome's shortcut and changing Chrome settings (Set pages). Also, it made itself the default search engine and who knows what else. I thought that it must be µTorrent's doing. So I decided to:

1. Reinstall Windows once again
2. Give Tixity a try. To my surprise, just after installing Windows 8 and running Internet Explorer, I saw that very [en.v9.com](http://en.v9.com/?utm_source=b&utm_medium=eBP&utm_campaign=eBP&utm_content=hp&from=eBP&uid=WDCXWD5000AAKX-001CA0_WD-WCAYUEK9947799477&ts=1379096550) page again.

I'm now going to reinstall Windows once again, but move the content of the disk into a folder first, so that Windows doesn't inherit anything, if that's what's happening.

I'm open to your suggestions. I doubt reinstalling windows will do any better. Also, do you know by any chance what it is and where it came from? I saw a [similar report](http://forum.utorrent.com/viewtopic.php?id=138460) on µTorrent's forum.

**UPDATE** I reformatted the hard drive, installed Windows and I can't see [en.v9.com](http://en.v9.com/?utm_source=b&utm_medium=eBP&utm_campaign=eBP&utm_content=hp&from=eBP&uid=WDCXWD5000AAKX-001CA0_WD-WCAYUEK9947799477&ts=1379096550) anywhere now.

Comment: Sounds like something changed your DNS provider and/or it'd your ISP doing

Comment: Reinstalling Windows would certainly fix this unless other computers connected to your home network experience the same problem.

Comment: @Ramhound What it has to do with `DNS`?

Comment: A poisoned DNS would redirect your traffic and/or could in theory insert JavaScript to do it.  Either that your IE settings were modified along with your chrome settings of course if after a profile wipe it Still happened it Chrome the the poisoned DNS server is more likely

Comment: DNS server can insert `javascript`, you say? Not possible, at all.

Comment: @x-yuri - My ISP does it all the time.  Try changing your DNS server information, see if it helps, I bet it will

Comment: Than it's your ISP who inserts `javascript` (using a proxy-server apparently), not the `DNS` server. Also, I wonder, why my question was downvoted...

Answer (score -1):

You visited a site or loaded an app which buried en.v9.com into your Registry and, since Chrome's your default, it opens with Chrome.

If you edit c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts by opening Notepad with Run as Administrator ([steps shown herein](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/modify-your-hosts-file/)) to add this line

```
127.0.0.1       en.v9.com
```

then any request to go there ends up in the Bit Bucket,which works with all kinds of obnoxious websites summoned by crudware and crudsites with crud javascripts.